What are the consequences of the amount of salt in the ocean?
Consider the Dead Sea, some other high salt lakes.  They ahve very limited life.
Consider the big freshwater lakes.  Great Lakes, Baikal.  Big enough to have ocean sized storms.
Consider estuaries, where fresh river water mixes with sea water to form gradients of salinity.
Consider that at present oceans present a barrier for a fresh water species to wander planet wide.
My girlfriend and I were swimming in the Mediterranean Sea today and she asked this question. For this question assume that all of Earth's oceans have always had very low salt (NaCl) concentration. Low enough that a human could safely use it as drinking water.
How would it affect sea life? Evolution of life in general? Climate? Would it be roughly the same, just with freshwater fish, plants, etc. in the oceans?

I’m voting to close this question because (a) you're allowed to ask one and only one quesiton, (b) It violate's the [help/dont-ask]'s Book Rule (too broad), and (c) it's an off-topic high concept question (open-ended, opinion-based, answers have equal value, etc.). Worst of all, you can't get a sensible answer without knowing where all the salt is going, since it's not going to the oceans.

We are not a site for speculating about arbitrary hypothetical scenarios. We are only here to help you with specific worldbuilding problems you may have as part of establishing facts about your fictional world.

You are not planning to write the history of fictitious-Earth-with-freshwater-oceans. Suppose we could scramble up an answer: of what use would it be to our viewers?

Fun fact: the Mediterranean is more saline than the ocean as a whole, about 38‰ (and up to 40‰ in the eastern parts in summer) compared to an average of 35‰; this is because the Mediterranean has a severe water deficit, and is fed by vast amounts of water coming from the Atlantic and the Black Sea, which then proceed to evaporate leaving the salt behind.

The edit that was made reduced the scope from any impact upon the earth, to to any impact upon the oceans this is still too broad a question for this site. The edit also changed from asking about the impact of fresh water only, to the impact of salinity in general, which greatly expands the scope. The question still asks about the impact on sea life, evolution in general, and climate, this part of the question is what is too broad, and is why the question was closed.

Frame challenge: this is not actually possible. As rain falls and runs as rivers into the sea, it carries soil and minerals with it, and water-soluble minerals dissolve in it.
Sodium chloride is common and highly soluble so it gets dissolved in river water. There isn't very much in normal river water, but it accumulates in the sea. As sea water evaporates, the salt stays behind. Much of the salt that has ever been washed into the sea is still there. There is no way for Earth to have salt-free oceans after a few hundred million years, nor is it plausible on any planet with vaguely similar chemistry and geology.

Is there any easy "way" to have less NaCl or have it less soluble without changing Earth's composition or chemistry in general too much?

@Michael, FYI, There is no NaCl in the oceans. There are Cl- ions and Na+ ions, which would become NaCl when the water evaporates, but there are also K+, Ca2+, Mg2+, SO^2,4- and scads of others. A "salt" is just any combination of + and -. You would have to eliminate all ionic elements from the crust to make this happen, which would prevent the formation of life.

Not possible --> Perhaps the world has common chemicals in the ocean that attach to CL- and Na+ ions, thus making the oceans sweeter?

Wouldn't a very young earth have low salt levels in its oceans ? Before billion of years of erosion.

@Jemox: Lower, certainly. But it's hard for humans and fish to have evolved on a very young earth, and they are mentioned in the question.

As John Dallman's answer points out, salt collects in the oceans after being dissolved on land and washed into the sea via rivers. Having freshwater oceans implies dramatically reducing the amount of salt on the planet. The trouble is, salt is crucial for the normal functioning of nerves and muscles and helps regulate fluids in the body, and chlorine helps regulate blood PH and pressure 1. So we cannot just remove a lot of sodium and chlorine. Life also needs a substitute material that plays the same roles as sodium and chlorine.

Find substitute materials that incorporate sodium and chlorine which life on that planet can ingest and then digest into sodium chlorine. Then for some reason, life would need to process the sodium chloride into something else that is not a salt before it exits the body, otherwise you are putting salt back into the environment where it washes out to sea making freshwater oceans salty after long enough periods of time.

Or find a source of ions that don't involve sodium or chlorine.


The trouble is, sodium and chlorine really like to bond together. It takes 769kJ of energy to turn one mol of solid NaCl into Na+ and Cl– ions 2. That's 58.44 grams/2.06 ounces of salt 3. If you have sodium and chlorine on your planet, at some point it will end up as NaCl, which gets dissolved by rain, and washed into rivers that flow out to sea. And your freshwater oceans become salty.
So, you can have freshwater oceans, but I'm not so convinced you can have life without altering its chemistry to replace the roles that sodium and chlorine play in metabolism and cell function.
